# "Error: couldn't add user" in MongoDB docker stack using a secrets file on Windows

Tags: mongodb, docker-stack, docker-secrets

While trying to run a MongoDB docker instance with authorization managed by docker-secrets (with files), inspired by this [blog post](https://medium.com/@leonfeng/set-up-a-secured-mongodb-container-e895807054bd), I kept running into the following error:

```
2020-07-24T16:25:26.656+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: Error preflighting normalization: U_STRINGPREP_PROHIBITED_ERROR :
```

#### Setup

- Windows machine running docker with a WSL2 backend.
- latest mongo [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) from docker hub (version 4.2.8)
- docker secrets to manage the authentication credentials to the MongoDB database
- my composer file:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.5'
services:
  my_db:
    image: mongo
    command: --auth
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mongodb_root_password
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE: /run/secrets/mongodb_root_username
    secrets:
      - mongodb_root_password
      - mongodb_root_username
secrets:
  mongodb_root_password:
    - file: mongodb/.mongodb_root_password
  mongodb_root_username:
    - file: mongodb/.mongodb_root_username
```

- shell command to deploy docker stack

```bash
$ docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml my_db_stack
```

#### Problem

Unfortunately, the container kept dying. In the logs, I was able to find the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the problem was caused by **Windows-style line endings** in the `mongodb/.mongodb_root_password` and `mongodb/.mongodb_root_username` files. Those files were created on the Windows host, and then (I assume) were blindly copied to the container.

#### Solution

Using notepad++ I switched the line endings to Unix-style, which solved the problem.

To switch the line endings, I right-clicked the highlighted portion of the bottom bar in the image below, on Notepad++.
[image: Notepad highlight line endings]

Comment: So how you can have Unix-style in Notepad++?

Comment: @lyrio I edited the answer to answer your comment. Hope this helps.